# Metro.Mahapps Designer not showing

Tags: c#, xaml, mahapps.metro

Hi I've been struggling with this bug and I have no clue how to resolve this.

Basically the form designer giving me this error:

```
Error   2   Could not load file or assembly 'MahApps.Metro, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But the application can compile.
[image: Error]

```
xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
```

Comment: Looks like you've got as far as to actually use this namespace by creating some controls. Was it working at any point? Have you tried Rebuilding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just updated the Nuget Package and everything went back to normal